# no apk file exist phonegap project

Tags: java, android, cordova, ant, phonegap-build

im building simple project with phonegape using cli i created the project folder successfully but when i build it using build command or build release it show me [image]

and there is no bin folder or any apk files i tried build android --release and it is not working 
i installed java ,Apache ant and android sdk correctly .

i think there is something wrong with apache ant but i didn't know what is that 
i want generate apk file help

phonegap version is 4.2.0-0.24.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your command is successfully ran, the Ant, Android SDK and Java are correctly installed since it would detect those missing.

And since the command is successfully ran, you should be able to find the files under `platforms/android/bin`.